# Can I have node.js listen on a non-standard port when hosted on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, port

I'm building a node.js app and am experimenting with hosting it on Heroku. It seems that to make my app available to the world, I need to listen like this:

`app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);`

I'd like to have my app listen on port 8080. Is this possible in Heroku? Can I change the value of process.env.port? It seems to be some kind of reverse proxy that I might not have control over.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. Heroku tells your application which port your application is required to listen on. The required interface between Heroku and your application is the `PORT` environment variable: your application must look for and use it. Your application is not able to listen on any other port except the port that Heroku tells your application it must listen on. Heroku tries to open a TCP connection to your application on that port and, if sixty seconds elapse since Heroku started your application and your application isn't listening on that port, Heroku figures your application is broken and shuts it down.

Comment: Bah - thats what I was afraid of. Guess I'll check out Joyent smart machines next.

Comment: One more question - can I listen on port 443 for SSL? Is there an env.SSLPORT type environment variable?

Comment: No, your application does not handle SSL. Heroku provides (as an addon service) a reverse proxy in the Heroku routing layer, with its own IP address, and copies your certificate and private key onto that reverse proxy. That reverse proxy terminate the SSL connection from the browser and forwards the HTTP requests to one of your dynos unencrypted. Your application dyno will be listening on some random high port (like port 32,654) that Heroku tells it to listen on, and the Heroku routing layer knows to forward HTTP requests to your application listening on that port.