# Run proxy server by nodejs on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

Hi i try to run nodejs based proxy server

https://github.com/tec27/node-argyle

just found that

```
var argyle = require('argyle');

var server = argyle(8080, '127.0.0.1');
server.on('connected', function(req, dest) {
    req.pipe(dest);
    dest.pipe(req);
});
```

this code works on local browser can connect and run

tried to push it heroku and run

procfile :

```
worker: node app.js
```

Package.json

```
 {
  "name": "proxy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "argyle": "*"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x",
    "npm": "1.1.x"
  }
}
```

do i miss anything
or try to open specified ports @ heroku not allowed?

Comment: See this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459166/can-i-have-node-js-listen-on-a-non-standard-port-when-hosted-on-heroku