# Heroku UCC SSL Certificate Not Working

Tags: ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate

I have a UCC SSL certificate which holds up to 10 domain names and when I browse to a page using the certificate I get an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

Here's what I've done:

- Purchased a UCC certificate
- Created a Heroku SSL endpoint
- Uploaded the certificate: `heroku certs:add server.crt server.key`
- Checked the certs: `heroku certs:info`

Info returns:

```
Fetching SSL Endpoint blah-1234.herokussl.com info for app-name... done
Certificate details:
Common Name(s):domain.com
            www.domain.com
            others......

Expires At:     2015-05-25 23:48 UTC
Issuer:         /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=www.domain.com
Starts At:      2014-05-25 23:48 UTC
Subject:        /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=www.domain.com
SSL certificate is verified by a root authority.
```

- `heroku certs`

Gives:

```
Endpoint                  Common Name(s)                                                                               Expires               Trusted
------------------------  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  --------------------  -------
blah-1234.herokussl.com   www.domain.com, domain.com, ..........                                                       2015-05-25 23:48 UTC  True
```

- Updated the domain to point to blah-1234.herokussl.com

CName:

```
www   blah-1234.herokussl.com   TTL1hr
```

- Waited TTL
- Run a curl test: `curl -kvI https://www.domain.com`

Response:

```
* About to connect() to www.domain.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 50.19.XXX.XXX...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 54.204.XXX.XXX...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 23.21.XXX.XXX...
* Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

The http urls work fine.

Any idea why this is happening? Is this because I'm using a UCC certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tech support guys at Heroku suggested removing and recreating the SSL end-point add-on and that solved the problem.

Comment: Same problem. Also command `heroku certs:info` produces error: `undefined method []' for nil:NilClass
~/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/certs.rb:204:in display_certificate_info'`. Re-adding the certificate (not add-on) fixed that.

Answer (score -1):

> `* Connection refused`

These are no certificate errors, either your web server does not listen on port 443 or there is a firewall in between which is blocking connections.

Comment: In this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459166/can-i-have-node-js-listen-on-a-non-standard-port-when-hosted-on-heroku @yfeldblum comments that the Heroku SSL app is a reverse proxy and that the web server using it should only listen on process.env.PORT. Does this mean that there is a problem with the reverse proxy / firewall?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Heroku, but "Connection refused" means, that the server does not accept the connection. But a reverse proxy needs first to accept a connection before it can forward it (and maybe find out that forwarding fails), so there should be another error in this case.